# Setting up celery beat task to run on multiple weekdays

Tags: django, celerybeat, django-celery-beat

I have a task that I'd like to run on Tuesdays, Wednesdays and Thursdays only. I have it setup as follows:

```
'schedule': crontab(
            day_of_week='2,3,4',
            hour=19,
            minute=0)
```

The task appears to run only on Tuesday though. Is the above the accepted way of specifying the weekdays or should it be `'tue, wed, thu'`?

Answer (score 1):

Due to [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.schedules.html#celery.schedules.crontab.day_of_week) int-based format should be (list of) integers from 0-6, in your case it should be:

```
day_of_week=[2,3,4]
```